# install update via Testflight doesn't minimise browser in iOS8

Tags: ios8, testflight, ota, enterprise-distribution

I use enterprise distribution (Testflight) for my iOS app, and I have problem described below:

- I am in Safari on testflightapp.com and I click on install button for my app
- I get confirmation dialog and I click on install button in this dialog
- App is installing, but safari isn't minimise, so user doesn't have feedback about installation (in iOS7 browser is minimised correctly)

Is there any workaround for this inconvenience?

Comment: Press the home button.

Comment: I know that app is installing :) I ask about automatic workaround, because it's poor UX for my users and they click several times on install button, because they didn't see progress of installation.

Comment: move them over to the test flight  app on the App Store. Or advise them that they need to close it...

Comment: I wish there was an option to downvote such idiotic comments like you are posting. "Press home button/move to app store" is NOT even close to the solution. @topic, did you find this change documented anywhere?